# What's the real wavelength of a LED

Tags: led, led-strip

If an LED emits some light: Does this really equal the wavelength that I have set or is it dependent on the LED's properties?

By the way, how to set some light on a LED-strip? I already can control the strip with an Arduino, but is theres a certain code that allows you to make the LED emit light in a given wavelength?

Alternatively: Is it acceptable to use Phillips Hue Led light and set the wavelength with applications like these: https://academo.org/demos/wavelength-to-colour-relationship/

What I actually want to do: building a spectroscope and using some predetermined wavelength as calibration.

Edit: Thank you for your useful hints!

Comment: Use a laser LED (low power of course).

Comment: "the wavelength you have set": I'm confused, where does one *set* the wavelength of an LED? Are you perhaps confusing colored light with monochromatic light?

Comment: don't you calibrate a spectroscope by observing spectral lines of a known substance?

Comment: Use a mercury-argon lamp. These can be had for as little as about US$10 (in the US, anyway.) These will firstly emit a strong set of lines for argon in the first minute or so of operation, and as they heat up, transition towards strong mercury lines. The combination of both mercury and argon will provide good coverage (and all-important doublets) for the visible spectrum -- assuming that is your calibration goal. I've used these many times in calibration Ocean Optics spectrophotometers with visible wavelength gratings, for example.

Comment: Please show we’re you have got an LED with _tuneable_ wavelength.

Comment: it's this one: https://www.amazon.com/CHINLY-Individually-Addressable-Waterproof-waterproof/dp/B01LSF4PYW?th=1. For my purposes it doesn't have to be super accurate. So if I tune the LED-Strip to white light, I should get 3 lines, each for red green and blue, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wavelength of light emitted by an LED is determined mainly by the material it is manufactured from, with some slight adjustment possible due to the geometry and doping profile. For example, gallium phosphide produces red or amber LEDs, and indium gallium nitride produces blue LEDs.

If you buy a "LED" with adjustable color, it is actually a combination of three LEDs with different colors (red, green, and blue) and the color adjustment comes from turning them on in different ratios of brightness. There will not be just one wavelength present in the output from this device, but three.

How the color of a specific adjustable LED is changed depends on the details of how that device is designed.

> building a spectroscope and using some predetermined wavelength as calibration.

You could use the tunable LED as a reference for the three specific wavelengths used in your tunable LED. But it probably won't be as accurate as you want since the spectra of the individual LEDs are relatively broad (compared to the resolution usually desired from a spectrascope), and is likely to shift depending on the LED's temperature.

A better solution is probably to use either a set of lasers with known wavelengths, or something like a mercury or sodium lamp that emits light with a set of well known narrow wavelength lines.

Answer (score 5):

You can't set the wavelength of the light emitted from an LED.  The wavelength is fixed.  It is set by the materials in the LED.

RGB LEDs don't vary the wavelength.  They change the brightness of a red, a green, and a blue LED to mix different colors.

You can't generate your needed spectroscope calibration color using RGB LEDs.

Comment: Calibration likely does not need a variable source, since that would be quite hard to achieve.  If the trend of the spectroscope is predictable, having two or three known peak wavelengths could be enough for calibration.  I would guess traditional calibration used a few elemental sources; probably someone has evaluated LED's as a simple replacement and published findings on their (un)suitability.

Answer (score 1):

> Alternatively: Is it acceptable to use Phillips Hue Led light and set the wavelength with applications like these: https://academo.org/demos/wavelength-to-colour-relationship/

Wavelength and color are very different things.  That Phillips Hue will let you change the color, but the wavelengths it emits are fixed.  Conversely, you spectrometer measures wavelength.

> What I actually want to do: building a spectroscope and using some predetermined wavelength as calibration.

I suggest asking this question directly since most of the answers you're going to get are not going to help you do what you want.  But no, this is not going to work.  LEDs are broadband, so they won't work for calibration.  A laser is better, but even that won't be very accurate because the wavelength emitted by a laser varies between devices and with temperature and current.

What you're looking for a is a wavelength calibration standard.  The best option for these are neon or argon lamps, since they emit a handful of very specific, very narrow wavelengths that do not depend on anything external:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas-discharge_lamp

If you look online you can find lists of different lamp types with their exact emission wavelengths.  You can buy models specifically for calibration online, or try to find a used one.

Answer (score 0):

A typical LED is not monochromatic, it emits a range of wavelengths.

Some LED bulbs allow you to set the color temperature, but these have an even wider range of wavelengths, they set the color by varying the ratio of different color LEDs.

[image]

https://www.kingbrightusa.com/images/catalog/SPEC/WP7113IT.pdf

Comment: I feel like this answer is just vague enough that it may confuse the OP more than help them. Yes, a typical LED emits a **range** of wavelengths, but it is a relatively narrow range and this doesn't mean that the wavelength can be **tuned**, which is what the OP was asking about. And when you talk about **color temperature** you are really using the word **color** loosely.